# How to use shell script to call bin file

Tags: linux, shell

I want to call an executable file from a shell script. So I have written some code in a file named `start.sh`. The code is:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

source env34/bin/activate
```

(I want to use the file "activate"). After that I execute

```
./start.sh
```

on the command line, but it does not work.

Comment: Is the executable flag set?

Comment: Please tell us more! What won't work? Did you recieve an error message? Which one? What's result code `$?` after a try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `source`.  `source` tells the interpreter (your shell) that the file should be loaded directly as a shell script.  You're not running a shell script, you're running an executable ("bin"), so you just invoke it directly, without `source`.

Bonus tip: if the last thing your script does is to invoke this other binary, you can use `exec` to actually replace your running script with the binary, so the script is no longer running at all.  Some people like this, because it avoids starting one more process, and keeps the output of `top` and `ps` leaner:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec env34/bin/activate
```

Note that nothing in the script after the `exec` line will run, so this only applies in certain cases.  But "launcher" scripts are one good case for this.